# How can I getting rid from base64string in the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string

I am retrieving image from database like this:

```
public ViewResult Details(int id = 0)
{
    vm.ImageToShow = Convert.ToBase64String(model.Picture)
    return View(vm);
}
```

The `Picture` definition:

```
public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
```

And I am showing it in the `View` like this:

```
@Html.Raw("<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," + Model.ImageToShow + "\" 
onclick='javascript: window.open(\"data:image/jpeg;base64," + Model.ImageToShow + "\")'/>")
```

When I click on it. it opens a new tab and show image but the URL is showing all base64 string like `data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGg.....`. How can I getting rid of this and show a short url with image name or anything else?

Comment: Have an action return the image

Comment: @RyanSearle I've updated my question and I showed my action method also.

Comment: If you don't want Base64, then the obvious answer would be...don't use it. Send the URL of the image in your result instead of a base64 string. However, it doesn't look like you may actually have a URL for it, since you're storing it as a byte array. Has it come from a DB by any chance? Not sure you're really going to be able to overcome this, unless the answer below will work. What's the problem with base64 anyway? It works.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ViewResult Details(int id = 0)
{
    //vm.ImageToShow = Convert.ToBase64String(model.Picture)
    vm.ID = id;
    return View(vm);
}

public FileResult Image(int id = 0)
{
    ..
    return File(model.Picture,"image/jpeg");
}


@Html.Raw("<img src=\"image?id=" + Model.ID + "\" 
onclick='javascript: window.open(\"image?id=," + Model.ID + "\")'/>")
```